# Bulma panels, how to nest containers inside a panel?

Tags: html, css, forms, panel, bulma

I'm attempting to group input controls in panels to make a page look cleaner.  Before using panels the controls looked like this:

[image]

markup for above:

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Patient Name, First</label>
      <div class="control has-icons-left">
        <input class="input is-primary" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Mother Name, First</label>
      <div class="control">
        <input class="input is-info" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Patient Name, Last</label>
      <div class="control has-icons-left">
        <input class="input is-primary" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Mother Name, Last</label>
      <div class="control">
        <input class="input is-info" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I try to nest that same group in a panel, the columns break:

[image]

markup:

```
<nav class="panel">
  <p class="panel-heading">
    Account Basics
  </p>
<div class="panel-block">

<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Patient Name, First</label>
      <div class="control has-icons-left">
        <input class="input is-primary" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Mother Name, First</label>
      <div class="control">
        <input class="input is-info" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Patient Name, Last</label>
      <div class="control has-icons-left">
        <input class="input is-primary" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Mother Name, Last</label>
      <div class="control">
        <input class="input is-info" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</nav>
```

Is there a way to do what I am wanting, to just group an existing control structure inside of a panel?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to try to remove the columns and try something similar to the "From" field in [this Bulma example](https://bulma.io/documentation/form/general/#horizontal-form). You can see this with your form in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqLzrk38/1/)

```
<nav class="panel">
  <p class="panel-heading">
    Account Basics
  </p>
  <div class="panel-block">
    <div class="field is-horizontal">
      <div class="field-body">

        <div class="field">
          <label class="label">Patient Name, First</label>
          <div class="control has-icons-left">
            <input class="input is-primary" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label class="label">Mother Name, First</label>
          <div class="control">
            <input class="input is-info" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label class="label">Patient Name, Last</label>
          <div class="control has-icons-left">
            <input class="input is-primary" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label class="label">Mother Name, Last</label>
          <div class="control">
            <input class="input is-info" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```